# Crontab -e not working. but crontab -l works

Tags: cron, amazon-lightsail

I use an Amazon Lightsail Lamp Server.

I am trying to edit a CRON job, which I setup previously using crontab -e but the editor keeps returning 964 and a blank page.

crontab -l shows the content of the file.

Any tips ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The issue was with the text editor used by my terminal. 
These were the steps I took :

```
export EDITOR=/bin/nano
source ~/.bashrc
echo $EDITOR
export VISUAL="/bin/nano"
```

Comment: Add the two `export` lines in your `.bashrc`